# How to make the sub nav disappear while other sub nav show up while hover

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I setup this main nav:

```
<ul class="menu12">
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/">About</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Offices</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/">Services</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Web Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Internet</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">testing &gt;</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">test 1</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a href="/">test 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">test 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">testing &gt;</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/">test 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/">test 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/">test 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/">test 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/">test 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/">test 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">test 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/">Hosting</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Domain Names</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Broadband</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/">Contact Us</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">U K</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">France</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">USA</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Australia</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
 </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/williamdickson/GK8eS/

So for that example is the landing page of item 'test 2'. When you hover any other main items like 'About', or 'contact us', their sub items are overlaying on top of the current items.

What I want is when you hover on other 'non-selected' class items, their sub items show up and the current 'selected' item will be disappear. Like how it works on here: http://jsfiddle.net/williamdickson/2n4hR/

Thank you

Comment: is there an example you can provide us of the working behavior? i'm having a difficult time understanding you

Comment: Hi @Kristian, i cant find the ideal example on the net so far. the one i did on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/williamdickson/GK8eS/ is kind what i after but not 100%. I will add more content in now.

Comment: @Simpledog if you have a working example, what's the problem? is the working example not doing what you want it to?

Comment: @kennypu its not working exactly the way I want it to. 

http://jsfiddle.net/williamdickson/GK8eS/: other items gets overlay when hover

http://jsfiddle.net/williamdickson/2n4hR/: 'selected' class item not show up while landing on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you're already using jQuery, all you need to do is remove any occurrences of `.selected`  in an .hover() event. change your jquery code to this for the first fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').hover(function() {
        $('li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected');
    });
    $('li.selected').parents('li').addClass("selected");
});
​
```

note, although this does what you want it to do, once you hover your mouse over something, it will remove the initial red high light of the currently selected page. I'd suggest using a different class for the change in text color.

Comment: thank you! Now I know where I went wrong... Yeah thanks for pointing the 'side effect' out, I might use onclick instead hover to avoid the issue. Big thanks again.